# Русификация мануала Yii2

Tags: framework, php, yii

Изучаю фреймворк Yii2 пару дней,  вот вижу, что есть русифицированная документация по 1.1, а по 2 - нету. Как думаете, будет ли и как скоро русифицированный мануал по api Yii2?

Comment: @Юра Сучко а Вы не ждите, а [помогите русифицировать документацию](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/translation-workflow.md). Релиз Yii2 случился лишь в середине октября прошлого года. Проект свободный, а потому, разработчики не стеснены временными рамками, и вообще, никому ничем не обязаны.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот все, что есть: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru

Answer (score 3):

Вот появилось:
[Yii2 полное руководство](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2-guide.ru.pdf)